# Google Drive search not finding trashed files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to fetch both trashed and non-trashed files modified (or trashed) after a certain time.  This is my code:

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('(trashed = true or trashed = false) and (modifiedDate > "2017-11-20T15:15:53.012Z"');
```

Unfortunately, it only return non-trashed files.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?  (I tried just trashed = true but that did not work either.)

Also, if it does work the file.getParents() call will return the folder it was in before it was trashed, correct?

Edit: Why was this downvoted?  The code is listed and it is relevant to others.  Don't see how it could be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why modifiedDate doesn't work for trashed files. But you can use the below function as a work around.

```
function driveFiles() {
    var requiredFiles = [];
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("trashed = true");
    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        if (Utilities.formatDate(file.getLastUpdated(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") > "2017-11-01 15:15:53") {
            var parentFolder = file.getParents();
            if(parentFolder.hasNext()){
              requiredFiles.push("File Name:"+file.getName() + " was located inside '" + parentFolder.next().getName()+"'");
            }
        }
    }
    Logger.log(requiredFiles)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can get all trashed files and loop through them checking the modified time.  However, there are many thousands of trashed files and I worry about the time it would take.